# How To run vb.net with vbs scheduled task

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a windows scheduled task to open a .vb script, but when i run the task, it just opens the .vb script and does nothing else. Is there a .vbs script that will open my .vb script visual studio and run my sub?

I have a .vbs script that will open excel and run macros, just not sure how to do it with visual studio

The sub runs fine when i do it manually in visual studio

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: you probably want to run `wscript.exe path\to\script\name`.

Comment: What do vb.net and running a VBS to do with eachother? What is in the .vb?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Vb.Net

Answer (score 0):

It does have something to do with VB.NET. Although it took me a day to see the real question.

**How to run a VB.NET .vb file from vbs.**

You have to compile it. Here's an article about how to do that.

[appactivate between multiple internet explorer instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396122/appactivate-between-multiple-internet-explorer-instances/23434935)

Although the sample given doesn't work 7 and later because of a name conflict. Rename sendmail to something else for 7 and later.

If a limited user you need to manually add the registry entries to `hkcu\software\classes`. Do this by exporting as a `reg` file (`regasm /reg`) and search and replace `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and merge it with `regedit` or `reg`.

Also if you put in extra brackets around statements and subs vbscript code works in VB.NET mostly.

See this for how to run vbscript code in vb.net.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting